# Avoiding semantic coupling with Java Collection interfaces

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

These days I am reading the Code Complete book and I've passed the part about coupling-levels (simple-data-parameter, simple-object, object-parameter and semantic coupling). Semantic being the "worst" kind:

> The most insidious kind of coupling occurs when one module 
>   makes use not of some syntactic element ofanother module but of some semantic 
>   knowledge of another module’s inner workings.

The examples in the book usually lead to run-time failures, and are typical bad code, but today I had a situation that I'm really not sure how to treat.

First I had a class, let's call it `Provider` fetching some data and returning a `List` of `Foo`'s.

```
class Provider
{
   public List<Foo> getFoos()
   {
      ArrayList<Foo> foos = createFoos();//some processing here where I create the objects
      return foos;
   }
}
```

A consuming class executes an algorithm, processing the `Foo`'s, merging or removing from the `List` based on some attributes, not really important. The algorithm does all of it's processing with the head of the list. So there is a lot of operations reading/removing/adding to the head.

(I just realized I could have made the algorithm looking like merge sort, recursively calling it on halves of an array, but that doesn't answer my question :) )

I noticed I'm returning an `ArrayList` so I changed the providing class' `getFoos` method to return an `LinkedList`. The `ArrayList` has O(n) complexity with head removals, while `LinkedList` has constant complexity. But it then struck me that I am possibly making a semantic dependency. The code will certainly work with both implementations of `List`, there are no side-effects, but the performance will also be degraded. And I wrote both classes so I can easily understand, but what if a colleague had to do implement the algorithm, or if he uses the `Provider` as a source for another algorithm which favors random access. If he doesn't bother with the internals, like he should not, I would mess up his algorithm performance.

Declaring the method to return `LinkedList` is also possible, but what about the "program to interface" principle?

Is there any way to handle this situation, or my design has flaws in the roots?

Comment: To be perfectly honest -- that's not a bad design; `LinkedList` is just a bad `List`.  Most code I've ever seen assumes it's dealing with a `RandomAccess` `List`, and it's not that unreasonable an assumption.

Comment: Agree with @LouisWasserman - LinkedList should almost never be used. You may replace all your LinkedList with ArrayDeque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general problem is, how does a producer return something in the form that the consumer prefers? Usually the consumer needs to include the preference in the request. For example

1. as a flag - `getFoos(randomOrLinked)`
2. different methods - `getFoosAsArrayList(), getFoosAsLinkedList()`
3. pass a function that creates desired List - `getFoos(ArrayList::new)`
4. or pass a desired output List - `getFoos(new ArrayList())`

But, the producer may have the right to say, this is too complicated for me, I don't care. I'll return a form that's suitable for most use cases, and the consumer needs to handle it properly. If I think `ArrayList` is best, I'll just do it. (Actually you may have a better choice - a ring structure - that suits both of the two use cases in consideration)

Of course, it should be well documented. Or you could be honest and return `ArrayList` as the method signature, as long as you commit to it. Don't worry too much about "interface" - ArrayList is an interface (in the general sense), Iterable is an interface, so what's so special about the `List` interface that's between the two.

There can be another criticism on your design - you return a mutable data structure so that the consumer can directly modify. That is less desirable than return a read-only data structure. If you could, you should return a read-only view of the underlying data; the construction of the view should be inexpensive. The consumer needs to do its own copy if it needs a mutable one.

Comment: The third and fourth options didn't even occur to me as I was writing, even though I've used both before. Doh!

Comment: It's hard to choose from all the nice answer, but I believe this is the most detailed one. Thanks to all, this was very constructive :) .
Point taken on the immutability!

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a compromise somewhere. In this case, there are two compromises that make sense to me:

1. If you don't know that all consumers of your `Provider` will be performing operations that are appropriate to a `LinkedList`, then stick with the signature that has return type `List` with implementation that returns `ArrayList` (`ArrayList` is a good all-around `List` implementation). Then within the calling method, wrap the returned `List` in a `LinkedList`: `LinkedList<Foo> fooList = new LinkedList<>(provider.getFoos());` Make the caller responsible for its own optimizations.
2. If you know that all consumers of your `Provider` are going to use it in a `LinkedList`-appropriate way, then just change the return type to `LinkedList` -- or add another method that returns a `LinkedList`.

I strongly prefer the former, but both make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could have the caller create the `LinkedList`, instead of the provider - i.e. change

```
List<Foo> foos = provider.getFoos();
```

to

```
List<Foo> foos = new LinkedList<>(provider.getFoos());
```

Then it doesn't matter what kind of list the provider returns. The downside is that an `ArrayList` is still created, so there is a tradeoff between efficiency and cleanliness.

Comment: Upvote from me: it's a very common thing to do, and quite reasonable most of the time.